# Подменить IP при DNS-запросе?

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, dns, bind9

Пытаюсь реализовать следующее:

Есть небольшая локальная сеть шлюз Ubuntu 14, на нем кэширующий bind. Нужно сделать следующее: при запросе пользователем DNS записи например `mail.ru`, нужно чтобы bind ответил ему айпишником скажем `127.0.0.1`. Но мой bind не является авторитетным для зоны `mail.ru`. Как это реализовать?

У меня была идея прописать себя мастером для зоны "." и в файле `root.db` прописать `mail.ru : 127.0.0.1`. Это не сработало,сервер не отдает вообще ответы DNS, клиенты в свою очередь сразу же начинают работать через вторичный DNS, который прописан у них в `resolv.conf`. Прошу помощи. Спасибо!

Конфиг:

```
acl guest_net {
        localhost;
        localnets;
        };

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        auth-nxdomain no;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        recursion yes;
        allow-query {guest_net; };

        forwarders {

        217.**.***.*;
        217.**.***.**;

        };
        forward only;
```

Comment: iptables завернуть все обращения от пользователей к 53 udp порту на свой bind

Comment: Зачем мне это делать? если у них мой днс прописан как первичный в resolv.conf и он отлично отрабатывает, пока я не ставлю bind мастером для зоны "."

Comment: а причем тут "." если у них ваш dns прописан как первичный то они вообще все запросы шлют вам. клиенты сами не умеют лазить по дереву dns. они не будут у вас выяснять где ru и слать запросы ему. они целиком запрос mail.ru. отдадут вам. для этого собственно сервер им и нужен. если вы просто поднимите у себя зону mail.ru то они отлично будут получать нужные вам ответы

Comment: Т.е. мне достаточно прописать:
zone "mail.ru" { 
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/mail.ru"
};
И создать файл /etc/bind/mail.ru и в нем добавить
mail.ru     127.0.0.1 
И оно заработает? а как правильно описать файл mail.ru?

Comment: да, заработает. Файл зоны самый простой, SOA, NS указывающую на ваш же сервер. A запись для "mail.ru." и возможно еще A для "*" что бы поддомены так же определялись

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я кеширую в dmsmasq.
В конфиге

```
...
addn-hosts=/etc/banner_add_hosts
expand-hosts
...
```

В файл `/etc/banner_add_hosts` добавить записи в формате `/etc/hosts` и всё заблокировано.

Настройку dnsmasq для только кеширования dns если не найдете - пишите коммент. Дополню как тут отключить dhcp.